# How to get an android application ( cccleaner) automatically run every 3 minutes?

Tags: java, android

I have installed an android application (ccleaner) that I would like to automatically run every 3 minutes but I don't know if I have to program it (and if so in which language) or use another application for this purpose.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use android service which run your logic every 3 minutes.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I've found this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html but it does not explain (I haven't found it) where and/or how to write the code.

Comment: Just an FYI doing something like this will murder your phone if you do it every 3 mins.

Comment: Also, CC cleaner doesn't really do anything in terms of memory optimizations which is presumably what your targeting. It's a bit of a pseudo effect, and it definitely won't make up for the shortened battery life caused by running the task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to program it in **Android** :

1. Use and Intent Service for the background task.
2. Implement an Alarm Manager to start that intent service after every 3 seconds.

Follow the following tutorials :

1. Intent Service tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

2. Simple tutorial to implement Intent service in alarm manager.

http://androidtechlaunch.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-and-intent-service-for.html